# Can't login to Windows Small Business Server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, security, remote-access

I removed AD by cmd using dcpromo and now when trying to access and login after a reboot with the Administrator account I can't. Do I need to reset the password from a boot disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SBS 2003 cannot be demoted in the traditional sense. You can run `dcpromo` but you have in essence bricked the server (past a 7 day grace period that existed in SBS 2003 to allow for data transfer, I believe). SBS will eventually notice that it is not in a healthy, supported state and will automatically shut itself down repeatedly. You cannot log into it. Do not pass Go. Do not collect $200.

If you want a member server, you will need to install a standard, non-SBS edition of Windows.

Comment: So I can't create or edit an account? I have to reinstall the OS with a different version?

Comment: @TiffanyWalker Correct. Correct. (Or restore from a backup if you have one and absolutely must go back to a pre-destruction state)

Comment: Did not know that... ;/ I just needed it to run on a WORKGROUP so the other systems could access it. I'll just use Ent. version I have laying around instead.

Comment: SBS is a totally useless, ill designed piece of crap. Just install Standard server, and forget SBS ever existed.